# I want to get the lat-long of a city name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to move the google map to a city. The user can select the city name from the select box. I am required the lat-long of the selected city. When user select the city i have to find its lat-long.
I am using this code to move the map

```
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);
map.panTo(center);
```

Comment: the term you're looking for is 'geocoding' https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried it with below code

```
var address = city_name;
geocoder.geocode({'address': address},function(results, status){
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
    {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    }else
    {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Google geocoder. It's API is [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#Geocoding). With it's help you can take lat-long like so:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({
    address: "Your address here"
}, function(results, status) {
    // here you get your result
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer i will try it and then tell the result back to you.

Comment: I have done with this code                                                                     var address = city_name;
         geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
           if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
           
           } else {
             alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
           }
         });

Comment: Great. Can you accept the answer, please, if it helped you to solve the issue?